# Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render, handleRemove causing rendered more hooks error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

`fields` array contains different field objects, on every field using map function there is a remove button but `handleRemove` function is causing error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState([
  { name: "abc", value: "" },
  { name: "def", value: "" }
]);
```

...

```
{
  {fields.map((field, index) => {
    const [now, setNow] = useState(field.value);
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

    const handleRemove = (index) => {
      const newFields = fields;
      newFields.splice(index, 1);
      setFields(newFields);
    };

    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <TextInput
          onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
          onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
          onChangeText={handleChange}
          value={now}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            handleRemove(index);
          }}
        >
          <Ionicons name="close" style={[tw``]} size={22} color="#ddd" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  })}
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to create new State inside `.map()` function. How about using an array to store the states of fields item?

Answer (score 0):

The code is breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html): Only call hooks at the top level, don't call hooks inside ***loops***, conditions, or nested functions.

Effectively you should factor out most of the `fields.map` callback into a React component so the `useState` hooks are rendered with the JSX and not in the Javascript callback in the loop.

Example:

```
const Field = ({ field, handleRemove }) => {
  const [now, setNow] = useState(field.value);
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
        onChangeText={setNow}
        value={now}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleRemove}>
        <Ionicons name="close" style={[tw``]} size={22} color="#ddd" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

...

```
{fields.map((field, index) => {
  const handleRemove = () => {
    setFields((fields) => fields.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  return (
    <Field key={field.name} field={field} handleRemove={handleRemove} />
  );
})}
```

[image: Edit error-rendered-more-hooks-than-during-the-previous-render-handleremove-causing]

Note also the `handleRemove` logic was updated to avoid a state mutation. `Array.prototype.splice` mutates the array in-place.

Not ok:

```
const handleRemove = (index) => {
  const newFields = fields;   // <-- newFields is reference to state
  newFields.splice(index, 1); // <-- .splice mutates state
  setFields(newFields);       // <-- same reference set back into state
};
```

Ok:

```
const handleRemove = () => {
   // .filter returns new array reference
  setFields((fields) => fields.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
};
```